# how to change python customedraw text on a timer? how?

Tags: python, windows, text, window, display

I want to display different text on a timer (maybe 40 seconds each)
currently its outputting 'some text' and then after a second it displays 'something new5'. it is completely skipping over 'something new1' - 'something new4' and only changing to 'something new5'

heres the code:

```
# New code: Define global
windowText = 'some text'


def customDraw(hWindow):
    global windowText
    time.sleep(1.0)
    windowText = 'Something new1'
    windowText = 'Something new2'
    windowText = 'Something new3'
    windowText = 'Something new4'
    windowText = 'Something new5'
    win32gui.RedrawWindow(hWindow, None, None, win32con.RDW_INVALIDATE | win32con.RDW_ERASE)
```

ive been working on this for a few days. I changed my method from using a remotefile of 'something new1' … 'something new5' to just putting in different "windowText =" this method seems more promising however the program skips right over a bunch of the text I want displayed on a timer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def customDraw(timer_id, time):
    global hWindow
    global counter
    global windowText
    if counter > 2:
        counter = 0
    text = ["test 0", "test 1", "test 2"]
    windowText = text[counter]
    counter = counter + 1
    win32gui.InvalidateRect(hWindow, None, True)
```